# Hide loop partitions / snaps in Krusader

Tags: partitioning, media, krusader, squashfs

I have installed Ubuntu for my dad instead of Windows recently and he really wanted an alternative to his favourite file manager Total Commander, so I went with Krusader which I myself have been using for ages.

However in Ubuntu 18.04 there seem to be a functionality called snaps in place which supposedly generates some loop partitions based on squashfs that get listed in Krusader's media list and by doing so are cluttering up that media list and are giving my dad a headache.

I have found out that one should be able to just remove snaps functionality:

[Small snap loop devices visible in gnome-disk-utility OR what is the function of snap ubuntu-core](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834093/small-snap-loop-devices-visible-in-gnome-disk-utility-or-what-is-the-function-of)

[Why are all snaps being mounted and listed as block devices or partitions for Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047456/why-are-all-snaps-being-mounted-and-listed-as-block-devices-or-partitions-for-ub)

[How can I disable snaps in gnome-software centre?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/982112/how-can-i-disable-snaps-in-gnome-software-centre)

[How do I hide the loop partitions in Nautilus created by Snap app?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/912538/how-do-i-hide-the-loop-partitions-in-nautilus-created-by-snap-app)

but to be honest I am a little afraid that I can delete something that will cause the system to be buggy. I would rather have an option in Krusader not to show any squashfs partitions. They are not being displayed in Disks or Nautilus and it would be great if I could set it up like that in Krusader too. I did look in preferences but cannot find anything relating to it.

So, is there a way to hide them in Krusader?

EDIT: here is the picture. It would not let me take a screenshot when the list is opened for some reason so I took a pic with my phone :/
[image: media list with squashfs]

Comment: You can replace many snaps with regular apps. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039411/how-can-i-replace-snap-application-such-as-gnome-calculator-with-a-deb &  https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391341 The real advantage of a snap is if you have an  old install and want newer versions of an app (but snaps not always updated either), or a new install and want some very old version. But I see no advantage of a snap where you can just install an app.

Comment: Can you please post an image to illustrate "some loop partitions based on squashfs that get listed in Krusader's media list and by doing so are cluttering up that media list"

Comment: @DKBose here you go, sorry for the poor quality, somehow when the list is opened the print screen key is not taking the screenshot, it is probably blocking all keyboard input. So I made a pic with my phone.

Comment: That's really a lot of snaps!!! You could take a "delayed" screenshot by setting a delay in your screenshot tool to give you enough time to switch to Krusader and to generate the image. I don't know much about Krusader so please explain how you got to the screen you posted? By the way, if you click on "MountMan" in the main toolbar, do you see an option in the lower left corner of the MountMan window to toggle "Show only removable devices"? It may take some time to respond.  Would that help?

Comment: You just click on the disk image in the media list and the list appears. When I click in the MountMan on 'show only removable devices' everything disappears, including mounted hard drives and the snaps.

This seems to be the default thing in Ubuntu now - I have the same thing on my PC as it is on my dad's PC (he has a lot of those too). We both have 18.04 and that is everything as far as it goes for similarities.

Answer (score 1):

> So, is there a way to hide them in Krusader?

A developer named [Soul Trace / S-trace](https://invent.kde.org/strace) has written the main part of the [source code](https://invent.kde.org/utilities/krusader/-/commit/9d80bd9f4d8251550a1311c4851de7fa919a104e) that allows hiding those unwanted entries :-)

If you can follow the steps of
https://invent.kde.org/utilities/krusader/-/blob/master/INSTALL
then you can build the git version of Krusader and get its latest features now (and even tell Krusader developers about what you find).

Comment: thank you for this option :)

Comment: works like a charm

Comment: so when will it be released in a krusader version?

Comment: oh, i see - this commit is already in master, but there were no releases since Aug, 2019.

So it should be in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is now present in Krusader 2.8.0. If you don't want to compile manually, you can download the binary from official package:

- Download .deb here https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/amd64/krusader/download.
- Open with Ark, open to data.tar.zst and extract usr/bin/krusader.
- Put it into ~/bin/krusader.