# /media has mysterious disks mounted containing imperfect copies of things like /bin and /etc

Tags: partitioning, mount, python, snap

Today I accidentally removed python from my computer. I reversed some of the damage by reinstalling the purged packages according to a .log file. However, after python was removed, six mysterious partitions appeared on my desktop. They are still there. The rest of the computer is back to normal.

[image: two slightly different versions of /etc/default]

**What I Know:** They are named disk, disk1, disk2... I am not the owner. They all have different contents, including things like an /etc/ folder. Upon investigation, these seeming duplicates have very different contents than their counterparts on my HD.

Some applications are missing as well. I installed one of them earlier today. I *think* they were all installed with snap rather than apt. I cannot see any other commonalities.

This is a pretty weird problem, yeah? I don't actually even know how to describe it. I am afraid to turn off my computer or unmount these drives, because I don't know what they *are* or if I need them.

Comment: Python is necessary for many parts of Ubuntu. Removing python is often fatal because it will cause widespread problems, as you are experiencing. My suggestion is to reinstall the OS and in the future don't remove things if you aren't sure that it won't cause problems

Comment: MOST of those mount points look like snaps.  There are configurations in Ubuntu out of the box to *not* show snap mount points and loop mounts in Nautilus.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/912538/how-do-i-hide-the-loop-partitions-in-nautilus-created-by-snap-app might be useful here with the going to each disk in `gnome-disks` and marking to hide them from UI