# how to remove nautilus fake volume /dev/loop

Tags: partitioning, nautilus, loop-device

today i installed nothing than ubuntu daily software update that happens once a day but I see two small size volume on the left pane of nautilus (120mb and 52mb). till now i only see such thing when i insert usb flash disk or phone into pc. the structure of files on these volumes are very similar to ubuntu root folder. trying losetup -a show many of these loop devices but the 2 visible devices in nautilus are:

```
/dev/loop36: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_17576.snap (deleted))
/dev/loop6: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_14056.snap (deleted))
```

how can i fix this? [here is the nautilus screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J48Tr.png)

Answer (score 1):

These devices appear to be created by snap and are required in order to use applications installed that way (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047456/why-are-all-snaps-being-mounted-and-listed-as-block-devices-or-partitions-for-ub)). However, as vanadium mentioned below, these should not normally appear in the file manager. I believe that the person asking [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/912538/how-do-i-hide-the-loop-partitions-in-nautilus-created-by-snap-app) had the same problem, so you should be able to hide those devices using the same method as the answers there. However, there may be a better/more permanent fix if the devices being shown is due to some other misconfiguration.

Comment: It is not normal that these appear in the file manager. The question is essentially how to remove them from the left pane of the file manager.

Comment: That's a good point; I'll edit my answer to mention that. As far as I can tell, the answers on the second question I linked should still work to hide them, but in that case I don't know if there is maybe a better/more permanent method to fix the problem.

Comment: fortunately the volumes disappeared after next boot. I can not say this for sure but i think the system was in need for restart after daily update. anyway the provided information was useful (at-least for me. low reputation didn't let me to up-vote the answer). thanks for attention and answer.